# Does IntelliJ IDEA reveal the method body when folding anonymous classes?

Tags: intellij-idea

Based on IntelliJ's documentation, when folding an anonymous class you should still be able to see the contents of the inner method.  See image below taken from their documentation:

[image]

This isn't the behavior I'm seeing though.  Here is what I see:

[image]

I can only seem to collapse the inner method contents or the entire anonymous class body.  Is this just an error in their documentation or is there a way to actually achieve this behavior?

======= **UPDATE** =========

I've accepted the answer from Peter Gromov, but there still seems to be something amiss with my version.  When I have files open and set folding closures by default (File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Folding -> Select 'Closures' under 'Collapse by default:'), it does seem to fold correctly as seen in the following image:

[image]

Notice that the expanded Because shows a single collapsible region in the margin.  Closing the file and reopening produces the following (after I collapse the first one):

[image]

When first opening the file, both of these statements are expanded (issue #1).  After collapsing the outer most region for the first statement, it folds over the entire anonymous class (issue #2) rather than how it worked before I closed the file.  Notice also that the second statement that I've left open has an additional collapsible region for the method of the anonymous class (issue #3).  This is how it behaves with the default folding settings for closures are turned off.  There's definitely something buggy here.  Since I've posted this question, there has been a new version released so perhaps the issue is only with the version I have (10.0.3), but as far as I know this is a fairly old feature.  I'd welcome any explanation as to why I might be seeing these issues (including "Works on my machine").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is called 'Closure folding' and can be turned on in the Code Folding settings.

Comment: This does seem to be the option I was looking for, but perhaps I have a buggy version because it only seems to work sometimes.  When I first turn it on, any files I already have open are folded.  However, closing the file and reopening it shows the sections expanded (the option is fold by default).  Additionally, after turning the option on before closing the file, there is only a single collapse for the statement in the margin.  After reopening, it shows one for the statement and an inner region for the method(s).  Definitely something strange going on there.

Comment: This is definitely a bug. It indeed works on my machine. As I'm going to need more information and SO doesn't seem to be a correct place for it, I invite you to http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/dashboard to file this bug and discuss the details there.