# Unexpected Token "}"")"

Tags: java, android, token

I'm trying to learn Java and I copy the code exactly from my lecturer's notes except I get one or two errors, which I think are small, basically unexpected token, nothing more. I tried finding invisible characters but that wasn't it.

```
public class PlayGame extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);

            Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end_game);
            startButton.setOnClickListener((View){
                    finish();
            });
        }
    }
```

The error is in second last line with "})" and a semicolon after "finish()" where the semicolon error says that ')', ',' or '}' expected...

Comment: Ahmed Alsanie not really, I said that there is no invisible characters as I typed the code myself, unless there is a way to check for them, but I doubt that's the case

Comment: Nop you are right its not! 
Removed the flag :)

Comment: This looks a bit like the AndroidStudio lambda-esque way of displaying code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999325/does-intellij-idea-reveal-the-method-body-when-folding-anonymous-classes - it's not legal java code though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `setOnClickListener` neends an `OnClickListener` instance as parameter (not the View something you are trying to pass).

so I guess you may need something like this

```
   startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v) {
          //... 
      }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution, in my lecturer's notes the part where you add the (new OnclickListener) there was an arrow which hid that part.